# When switching to ORDER BY ASC instead of DESC, it takes forever. What gives?

Tags: mysql

I am simply switching my query `ORDER BY` *from* `DESC` to `ASC`. No other changes.

My query:

```
SELECT * FROM `conversion_queue`
WHERE
    `processed_date` = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
    AND `created` <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MINUTE)
    AND `processed_status` = 'QUEUED'
ORDER BY `created` ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

I have the following indexes on the table:

```
Non_unique      Key_name            Seq_in_index    Column_name         Collation
0               PRIMARY             1               id                  A
1               client_id           1               client_id           A
1               merchant_unique_id  1               merchant_unique_id  A
1               created             1               created             A
```

What gives? Is there an additional index that I should add? This particular table has over a million rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is

```
`created` <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MINUTE)
```

If you order by `created` descending, MySQL can go to the index find the first value meeting the constraint, maybe go back a few records until the other constraints are met, and then stop right there because of `LIMIT 1`. However if the order reverses, then it has to scan the index from the very start until it finds the first record that meets all of the constraints which could take a while. A key on `(processed_date,processed_status,created)` could be of big help in that case, but you should always verify all of your queries with `EXPLAIN` to make sure the keys are being used as expected.

Comment: I thought it wouldn't take a long to go up since I have an index on that column and I have additional criteria. I ran an `EXPLAIN()` on the query above and for `possible_keys` and `key` columns, I get `created`. Does your suggestion of the new index still stand?

Comment: Yes. `created` is not a good index for this type of data access unless the query constraint is fully met in the first few records of the index allowing `LIMIT 1` to terminate the index scan. With the key on `(processed_date,processed_status,created)` MySQL can go straight to the first record that matches the constraint on `processed_date` and `processed_status`. If the first record does not match the constraint on `created`, we are done, the ones after that will not match either. If it does, we can serve the record and stop.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any indexes on processed_date and processed_status that are in your where clause.  You will probably want one index that covers all three with created as the last one.

Probably the reason DESC is faster is that it can look at the latest created and scan backwards through the created index and fetch records until the other two criteria match.  For ascending it has to start at the first entry in created and scan forwards and fetch records. The earlier entries probably are all processed, so it has a lot more to look through until it finds a match.

If you have covering index processed_date, processed_status, created then it can find the record by an index lookup.  You will probably find even the DESC speed would increase with this.